# Mean and variance of $X:=(k-3)^2$ for $k\in\{1,\ldots,6\}$.

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, means

I have a problem:

Let $X$ be a random variable from a dice, defined by $X:=(k-3)^2$ for $k\in\{1,\ldots,6\}$. The exercise is to find the mean and the variance of $X$.

- The probabilities are
  $$P(X=0)=\frac{1}{6},\ P(X=1)=\frac{1}{3},\ P(X=4)=\frac{1}{3},\ P(X=9)=\frac{1}{6}.$$
  Is it true that
  $$\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{k\in\{1,\ldots,6\}} P(X=(k-3)^2)\cdot (k-3)^2?$$
  If the answer is yes, the mean of $X$ will be
  $$\mathbb{E}(X)=P(X=4)\cdot4+P(X=1)\cdot 1+0+P(X=1)\cdot 1+P(X=4)\cdot 4+P(X=9)\cdot 9\tag{1}$$
  or 
  $$\mathbb{E}(X)=2\cdot P(X=1)\cdot 1+2\cdot P(X=4)\cdot 4+ P(X=9)\cdot 9?\tag{2}$$
  I'm confused with the definition of mean.

Comment: They're the same.

Comment: But are the probabilities correctly? I'm really not sure

Comment: Please replace the absurd $$\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{k\in\{1,\ldots,6\}} P(X=(k-3)^2)\cdot (k-3)^2$$
by the formula $$\mathbb{E}((Y-3)^2) = \sum_{k=1}^6 P(Y=k)\cdot (k-3)^2$$ where, in your case, $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1,\ldots,6\}$ hence $$\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}((Y-3)^2) = \frac16\sum_{k=1}^6 (k-3)^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already found the probability space, it is easier (especially for the variance) to calculate it as
$$\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{n\in\{0,1,4,9\}} P(X=n)\cdot n=\frac{19}{6}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! So, I've calculated the second moment of $X$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\frac{115}{6}$. Can it be true that $\mathrm{Var}(X)=\frac{329}{36}$?

Comment: @MathCracky Correct.